# get_search_query() not working with search queries with ampersand in it

Tags: theme-development

I am using plain simple code to make a search page

```
$argscontactdirectory = array(
            "s" => get_search_query(),
            'post_type' => array( 'expertarticle'),
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order'   => 'ASC',
    );
```

Above is the code I am using, however, when the search query contains the "&" character it simply doesn't work, if the search query is `M&M` the URL bar will show `?s=M&amp;M`

I tried many things, include `urlencode()`, but it doesn't work either.

A live example can be seen here:
http://sandbox.indiadairy.com/?s=hello&p_type=is

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_search_query` escapes the data for outputting to HTML. Can you try the following instead:

```
$argscontactdirectory = array(
        's' => sanitize_text_field( get_search_query( false ) ),
        'post_type' => array( 'expertarticle'),
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
);
```

Comment: I just had to wrap it in `urlencode` and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$argscontactdirectory = urlencode(
array(
        's' => sanitize_text_field( get_search_query( false ) ),
        'post_type' => array( 'expertarticle'),
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
)
);
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?